# Parsing logical expressions

Tags: python, string, parsing, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a task where I have to filter a Pandas DataFrame based on user specified logical expression. Now, I've seen a module called PyParser or LARK which I would like to use but I cannot seem to figure out how to set them up.

I have several operators like `CONTAINS`, `EQUAL`, `FUZZY_MATCH` etc. Also, I'd like to combine some expressions into more complex ones.

Example expression:

`ColumnA CONTAINS [1, 2, 3] AND (ColumnB FUZZY_MATCH 'bla' OR ColumnC EQUAL 45)`

As a result, I'd like to have some structured Dict or List with levels of operations in order of how to execute them. So, the desired result for this example expression would be something like:

```
[['ColumnA', 'CONTAINS', '[1, 2, 3]'], 'AND', [['ColumnB', 'FUZZY_MATCH', 'bla'], OR, ['ColumnC', 'EQUAL', '45']]]
```

or in form of dict:

```
{
  'EXPR1': {
    'col': 'ColumnA', 
    'oper': 'CONTAINS', 
    'value': '[1, 2, 3]']
  },
  'OPERATOR': 'AND', 
  'EXPR2': {
    'EXPR21': {
      'col': 'ColumnB', 
      'oper': 'FUZZY_MATCH', 
      'value': 'bla'
    }, 
    'OPERATOR': OR, 
    'EXPR22': {
      'col': 'ColumnC', 
      'oper': 'EQUAL', 
      'value': '45'
    }
  }
}
```

Or something like that. If you have some better way of structuring the result, I'm open for suggestions. I'm pretty new to this so I'm fairly certain this can be improved.

Comment: I see you already got an answer, but let me know if you're interested in a solution using Lark.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem :)

Seems like a relatively straightforward application of the [shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm.
I had written code to parse expressions like `"((20 - 10 ) * (30 - 20) / 10 + 10 ) * 2"` over [here](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/interview-notes/blob/master/notes/algo-ds-practice/problems/stack_queue/evaluate_expression/eval_expression_direct.py).

```py
import re


def tokenize(str):
   return re.findall("[+/*()-]|\d+", expression)

def is_number(str):
    try:
        int(str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def peek(stack):
    return stack[-1] if stack else None


def apply_operator(operators, values):
    operator = operators.pop()
    right = values.pop()
    left = values.pop()
    values.append(eval("{0}{1}{2}".format(left, operator, right)))


def greater_precedence(op1, op2):
    precedences = {"+": 0, "-": 0, "*": 1, "/": 1}
    return precedences[op1] > precedences[op2]


def evaluate(expression):
    tokens = tokenize(expression)
    values = []
    operators = []
    for token in tokens:
        if is_number(token):
            values.append(int(token))
        elif token == "(":
            operators.append(token)
        elif token == ")":
            top = peek(operators)
            while top is not None and top != "(":
                apply_operator(operators, values)
                top = peek(operators)
            operators.pop()  # Discard the '('
        else:
            # Operator
            top = peek(operators)
            while top is not None and top != "(" and greater_precedence(top, token):
                apply_operator(operators, values)
                top = peek(operators)
            operators.append(token)
    while peek(operators) is not None:
        apply_operator(operators, values)

    return values[0]


def main():
    expression = "((20 - 10 ) * (30 - 20) / 10 + 10 ) * 2"
    print(evaluate(expression))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I reckon we can modify the code slightly to make it work for your case:

1. We need to modify the way in which we tokenize the input string in `tokenize()`.
   Basically, given the string `ColumnA CONTAINS [1, 2, 3] AND (ColumnB FUZZY_MATCH 'bla' OR ColumnC EQUAL 45)`, we want a list of tokens:
   `['ColumnA', 'CONTAINS', '[1, 2, 3]', 'AND', '(', 'ColumnB', 'FUZZY_MATCH', "'bla'", 'OR', 'ColumnC', 'EQUAL', '45', ')']`.
   This would highly depend on how complex the input string can be and would require some string processing, but its fairly simple and I'll leave this to you.
2. Modify the `is_number()` function to rather detect things like `ColumnA`, `[1, 2, 3]` etc.
   Basically, everything apart from predicates `CONTAINS`/`FUZZY_MATCH`/`EQUAL`, operators `AND`/`OR` and parantheses `(`/`)`.
3. Modify `greater_precedence(op1, op2)` to return true in case `op1` is among `['CONTAINS', 'EQUAL', ..]` and `op2` is `['AND', 'OR']`.
   This is because we want the `contains` and `equals` to be always evaluated before `AND`/`OR`.
4. Modify `apply_operator(operators, values)` to implement logic of how to evaluate the boolean expression `ColumnA CONTAINS [1, 2, 3]` or the expression `true AND false`.
   Remember that `CONTAINS`/`FUZZY_MATCH`/`EQUAL`/`AND`/`OR` etc all are operators here.
   Probably you'll need to write a lot of if-else cases here as there can be a lot of different operators.

Comment: OK, thanks for the verbose and complete answer :) Seems like this is what I was looking for. I'll test it in the next few days.

Comment: Sure. Dont forget to accept the answer and close the question if it worked ;)